# Why does the python F string module not work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, format

I am making an adventure game in python 3.7.3, and I am using F strings for some of my print statements.  When running it in the terminal and sublime text, F strings give me an error.

```
import time
from time import sleep
import sys

def printfast(str):
    for letter in str:
        sys.stdout.write(letter)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.04)

name = input("\nWhat is your name?\n\n")

printfast(f("You are the mighty hero {name}. In front of you, there is a grand palace, containing twisting marble spires and spiraling dungeons.\n")
```

Comment: It should give you also a Syntax Error. You put a left parethesis after `f` that doesn't belong there

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it wrong. `f` isn't a function, it's more of an syntactic identifier. Whereas regular quotes `"` indicate the beginning of a regular string (or the end of any type of string), the token `f"` indicates the beginning of a format string in particular. The same idea goes for raw strings, indicated by `r"`, or binary strings, indicated by `b"`.

Instead of

```
f("You are...")
```

do

```
f"You are..."
```

Answer (score 0):

In `f("You ...)`, you're calling a function named `f` with the string as input parameter, and you don't have such a function hence the error.

You need to drop the enclosing parentheses `()` to make it a f-string:

```
f"You are the mighty hero {name}. In front of you, there is a grand palace, containing twisting marble spires and spiraling dungeons.\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

f-strings are not created using a function, it's a type of string, which you denote using `f''` (similar to `b''` or `r''`)

So try using:

```py
printfast(f"You are the mighty hero {name}. In front of you, there is a grand palace, containing twisting marble spires and spiraling dungeons.\n")
```